# Video Shortcodes not working in Wordpress

Tags: shortcode, videos

I have my own wordpress theme created, when I attach a video to the post it looks good while editing. After posting the post, showing the post comes out the following code but does not display the video or controls.

[video width="560" height="320" mp4="http://namefile.mp4"][/video]

Should I add some functionality to my theme in the functions?

WP Versión 4.6.1

Comment: You shouldn't have to add any functionality to your theme. Does it work with default theme active?

Answer (score 1):

According to WordPress codex here https://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode . You wrote the shortcode  wrong, you added mp4 instead of src

The correct way to write the shortcode Is like this:

[video width="560" height="320" src="http://namefile.mp4"]